# Upstart --user: how a processes started

Tags: upstart, ibus

I am trying to debug an issue in my user session. I am running on Ubuntu 16.04 which still uses `upstart --user` to manage the user session.

My problem is that some process in my user session is starting the ibus-daemon and other programms and I do not know which process is doing that.

When I run `pstree` I see that `ibus-x11`, `ibus-daemon` and other ibus programms are immediate child of `upstart --user`? Is upstart directly starting these processes and if so, where should I look for the configuration files that cause these processes to be started by upstart?

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu, Upstart in user mode reads configuration files from the following locations:

- `/usr/share/upstart/sessions/`
- `/usr/share/upstart/xdg/autostart/`
- `/etc/xdg/autostart/`

You can try deciphering `man 5 init` if you want more info.